# Allocate object and calling method in C python API

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, api

I want to instantiate a class and call its method using C python API. I don't know how to call the method of the object. I am using python 2.7 and gcc gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 
python code:

class mathops:
    def multiply(a,b):
        print "Will compute", a, "times", b
        c = 0
        for i in range(0, a):
            c = c + b
        return c

C code:

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc;
PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
int i;

if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: call pythonfile funcname [args]\n");
    return 1;
}

Py_Initialize();
pName = PyString_FromString(argv[1]);
/* Error checking of pName left out */

PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");

pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
Py_DECREF(pName);

if (pModule != NULL) {

    pClass = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, argv[2]);

    //pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, argv[2]);
    /* pFunc is a new reference */

    if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
        pObject = PyObject_CallObject(pClass, NULL)¶
```

/* how to call method ? */

```
        pArgs = PyTuple_New(argc - 3);
        for (i = 0; i < argc - 3; ++i) {
            pValue = PyInt_FromLong(atoi(argv[i + 3]));
            if (!pValue) {
                Py_DECREF(pArgs);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
                return 1;
            }
            /* pValue reference stolen here: */
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, i, pValue);
        }
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);
        if (pValue != NULL) {
            printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyInt_AsLong(pValue));
            Py_DECREF(pValue);
        }
        else {
            Py_DECREF(pFunc);
            Py_DECREF(pModule);
            PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (PyErr_Occurred())
            PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
    }
    Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
}
else {
    PyErr_Print();
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
Py_Finalize();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: [PyObject_CallObject](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallObject)??

Comment: You already have `PyObject_GetAttrString` and `PyObject_CallObject` in your code, which should be all you need to retrieve the method from `pObject` and then call it.